# How to add friction/damping to circle to circle prediction formula?

Tags: math, geometry, collision-detection, physics, easing

I've been working on determining the time at which two objects would collide, if they would at all. I had referenced this thread which was very helpful: [Circle-Circle Collision Prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369616/circle-circle-collision-prediction)

`(Oax + t*Dax - Obx - t*Dbx)^2 + (Oay + t*Day - Oby - t*Dby)^2 = (ra + rb)^2`

I was able to solve that for `t` but now I'm wondering how I would best apply drag/friction to it.

If ball1 is traveling at a fixed rate of 9, and ball2 is traveling at 7... this works great. Problem is that if their velocities will decrease over time.. so if we're covering a lot of ground, ball1 will end up traveling at 4 and so the collision result could change.

For example: Ball1 is traveling down a slight slope, gaining speed. Ball2 is going straight and losing speed.

I'm assuming that the part of this formula needing adjustment would be the `t*Dax`, `t*Dbx`, `t*Day`, and `t*Dby`. These appear to be linear, right? So I would want to replace these with something representing my damping.

There would probably be multiple things determining my damping such as: surface friction and gravity.. or could reference easing equations such as Robert Penner's equations in this file http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js

Thanks!

Edit:

Looked up some projectile motion formulas and was playing around with `d = V₀t - ½ at²` . Was wondering if combining that would be the trick, but not sure where/how it would be applied. I considered the following...

`(O₁x + (t·D₁x - a₁t²) - O₂x - (t·D₂x + a₂t²))² + (O₁y + (t·D₁y - a₁t²) - O₂y - (t·D₂y + a₂t²))² = (r₁ + r₂)²`

**Update** (*thanks to the post by willywonkadailyblah*)

After working with it a bit, here's a quick Javascript example of it working. You can find references to Vector classes and Quartic solvers online.

```
// p1 = c1 + (v1 * t) + 0.5 * a1 * (t ^ 2)
// p2 = c2 + (v2 * t) + 0.5 * a2 * (t ^ 2)

var p1c = new Vector(10,  50),
    p1v = new Vector(10, -10),
    p1a = new Vector( 5,   2),

    p2c = new Vector( 50,  10),
    p2v = new Vector(-10,  10),
    p2a = new Vector( -9,   0),

    r1  = r2 = 15,
    p1, p2,
    oc, ov, oa,
    A, B, C, D, E,
    q, r, s, t, u;

    var quadraticAnswers = solveQuadratic(p1c, p1v, p2c, p2v, r1);
    var quarticAnswers = solveQuartic( p1c, p1v, p1a, p2c, p2v, p2a, r1, r2 );

    console.log( "Quartic", quarticAnswers );
    console.log( "Quadratic", quadraticAnswers );
    console.log( "Best Quartic", quarticAnswers.bestAnswer );

    function solveQuartic(p1c, p1v, p1a, p2c, p2v, p2a, r1, r2) {
        // delta p
        oc = p1c.subtract(p2c);

        // delta v
        ov = p1v.subtract(p2v);

        // delta a
        oa = p1a.subtract(p2a);

        //
        A = oa.magnitude().pow(2).multiply(0.25);
        B = ov.multiply(oa);
        C = oc.multiply(oa).add( ov.magnitude().pow(2) )
        D = ov.multiply(oc).multiply(2);
        E = oc.magnitude().pow(2);

        q = A.x + A.y;
        r = B.x + B.y;
        s = C.x + C.y;
        t = D.x + D.y;
        u = E.x + E.y - Math.pow(r1 + r2, 2);  // hidden because of the issue with radius not adding up

        // the quartic/cubic/quadratic solver
        var ret = solveEquations(q, r, s, t, u);

        if (oa.x + oa.y < 0) {
            ret.bestAnswer = ret.x4 || ret.x3 || ret.x2 || ret.x1;
        }
        else {
            ret.bestAnswer = ret.x2 || ret.x1 || ret.x4 || ret.x3;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

VectorJS works well with this, but you have to manually add a `pow` method. https://evanw.github.io/lightgl.js/docs/vector.html

Here's a quartic/cubic/quadratic solver for JS. You'll need to do a fair amount of modification on the source to get it to work with your app or to translate it into other languages. http://www.freewebs.com/brianjs/ultimateequationsolver.htm

I was going to post a C++, but figured this would be easy for a lot of people and many people use JS nowadays.

Comment: Are you looking to implement rotational dynamics too? Or just linear?

Comment: Rotational dynamics would be awesome, because I'd love to add it... but I could live with linear for the moment if it's out of the realm of explanation.

Comment: Is your definition of friction constant or some simple function of time/velocity?

Comment: It's a constant friction. It's an arbitrary drag that slows the movement by... 0.32 or anything really. Eventually the object should slow to a stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to simulate surface friction / gravity, which most models at this scale assume to be constant.

SUVAT equations for the positions of each ball:

[image]

Need distance between centers < sum of radii - take square magnitude (self dot-product):

[image]

Let [image]

[image]

[image]

And then all you need to do is to solve this quartic equation to find the smallest positive real root. Easy!

Well OK. Here are two sites to help you:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785/is-there-a-general-formula-for-solving-4th-degree-equations

If you don't want to do this, then a fast iterative method such as Newton-Raphson will do; contrary to time-step based methods these *don't* limit the accuracy of the answers.

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for! Let me read through it more thoroughly.. but thanks for the post!

Comment: Awarding points because this is definitely the direction I was looking for even though I haven't broken it down/applied it yet. Will mark the answer correct once I run through it... (just to be thorough). 

Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: @MattKenefick np man, good luck with implementing that quartic crap :D

Comment: What do the δu and δp represent in the final line? I see δc, δv, and δa defined above.

Comment: Anyway, after some clarity on that comment above, I think I might be good to go. I've been doing a lot of research and experimentation on Newton-Raphson + general practices for approaching both cubic + quartic equations. It's going well so far and I'm excited to push this forward.

Comment: apologies for the late reply - they were meant to be delta v and delta c respectively, I was copying some rough notes :S the previous line is correct though

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I kind of suspected they were... but I wanted to make sure before I put a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: @MattKenefick :D sorry. typing LaTeX is so boring that your brain kinda just switches off mid-way and blindly follows what you've written on the piece of scrap paper in front of you