# How to shoot objects in movement?

Tags: c#, math, game-physics, bulletphysics

See my image below:

[image]

The black-right-arrow is my ship and the red circle my enemy (radius 1.2). Both are in movement without acceleration. I need kill the red circle with precision, what type of calculations can I use with only linear velocity, position, and radius data?

Note: The bullet has 0.5s of lifetime and the speed 40 and radius 0.2

I'm trying to implement this in C#.

```
public static Vector3 CalculatePreciseShootDirection(Vector3 shipPosition, Vector3 shipVelocity,
                                                         Vector3 targetPosition, Vector3 targetVelocity,
                                                         float bulletLifetime, float bulletSpeed)
        {
            Vector3 shipFuturePosition = shipPosition + bulletLifetime * shipVelocity;
            Vector3 targetFuturePosition = targetPosition + bulletLifetime * targetVelocity;
            Vector3 relativeDisplacement = targetFuturePosition - shipFuturePosition;
            float timeToTarget = Vector3Magnitude(relativeDisplacement) / bulletSpeed;
            Vector3 adjustedTargetPosition = targetPosition + timeToTarget * targetVelocity;
            Vector3 shootingDirection = adjustedTargetPosition - shipPosition;
            float shootingDistance = Vector3Magnitude(shootingDirection);
            float maxDistance = bulletLifetime * bulletSpeed;
            if (shootingDistance <= maxDistance)
            {
                return Vector3.Normalize(shootingDirection);
            }
            else
            {
                return Vector3.Zero;
            }
        }
        
        private static float Vector3Magnitude(Vector3 v)
        {
            return (float)Math.Sqrt(v.X * v.X + v.Y * v.Y + v.Z * v.Z);
        }
```

Comment: Step 1: rewrite the velocity of the red dot as the velocity _relative_ to your ship. The dot's position over time is now a line, and you can find the segment on that line that can be hit by a bullet given the values you stated.

Comment: If you aim at the center of the target, the radius information is useless, isn't it ?

Comment: Is the speed of the bullet absolute (always 20, in any direction) or to be added to the speed of the ship as in the real world ?

Comment: yes, all speed are constant, without acceleration.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't understanding, can you explain

Comment: The radius doesn't matter at all - you aim at the center anyway. I think your issue is that currently you always assume the full bullet lifetime .. what if we can intercept the target already before that?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11369616/3871028) And there you can get the formulation used

Comment: see [Projectile Aim Prediction with Target Acceleration and Bullet Deceleration Varying with Angle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71817221/2521214) and [C++ intersection time of 2 bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71808916/2521214) for some inspiration

Answer (score 1):

You need to add both velocities together and set that as the initial speed of the projectile.

like so:

> projectile speed = (**X**= V1.x+V2.x, **Y**= V1.y+V2.y)

Comment: But if I can't change the velocity of the projectile, I only change the direction.